# How to push array into array in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi all I have the following code:

```
$shops = array();
foreach($json as $var)
{
    if (in_array($var['shop'], $shops)) {}
    else
    {
        array_push($shops,$var['shop']);
        array_push($shops->$var['shop'],array('revenue' => 0, 'numberofbooks' => 0));
    }
}
```

I want the following:

```
Shops
  => shop1
    => revenue
    => numberofbooks
  =>shop2
    => revenue
    => numberofbooks
```

But inserting the third array does not work, can anyone help me?

Comment: You're using object child notation instead of array i.e. `obj->var` instead of `Arr[child]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$shops = array();

foreach($json as $var){
    if (!isset($shops[$var['shop']])){ // use ! as "not", and use isset()
        $shops[$var['shop']] = array('revenue' => 0, 'numberofbooks' => 0);
    }
}
```

PHP's `in_array()` checks if a value exists in the array not if a key exists..

Answer (score -1):

Try this (not tested)

```
$shop = array();
foreach($json as $var)
{
    if(!in_array($var['shop'], $shop)){
        $shops[$var['shop']] = array('revenue' => 0, 'numberofbooks' => 0);
    }
}
```